# Parse react component map to new component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to take a react component as input and map to a new component tree (replacing tags and modifying as desired). In this specific case, I would like to take a component written for DOM output and modify it to for native output.

So a very simplified component might go from:

```
<MyComponent>
  <p>foo</p>
</MyComponent>
```

to:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Text>foo</Text>
</MyComponent>
```

Bonus points for modifying individual tags props, such as adding `style` props, event handlers, et cetera. I know if there is an answer it won't be one-size-fits-all. I'm just hoping for some guidelines as to general approach/others who have encountered this use-case and pushed it forward.

Comment: How would you take the former as input in a react native application since `<p>` isn't valid JSX in that context?

Comment: I don't know. I've seen work towards "universal" react components that are platform-agnostic, like https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-primitives, which it seems to me is in this sphere. It is puzzling trying to figure out how to parse DOM-style jsx to native outside of a DOM context though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to work reasonably well, although passing styles down the tree is an open question. Well, at least we know that the transpilation from one set of tags to another is possible. Props https://stackoverflow.com/users/2578335/giles-copp

```
// traverse.js
import React from 'react';

export function kindOf(node) {
  if (node === null || node === undefined || typeof node === 'boolean') {
    return 'Empty';
  }
  if (typeof node === 'string' || typeof node === 'number') {
    return 'Text';
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return 'Fragment';
  }
  const { type } = node;
  if (typeof type === 'string') {
    return 'DOMElement';
  }
  return 'ComponentElement';
}

export function defaultTraverse(path) {
  const kind = kindOf(path.node);
  if (kind === 'Empty') {
    return path.node;
  }
  if (kind === 'Text') {
    return path.node;
  }
  if (kind === 'Fragment') {
    return path.node.map(path.traverse);
  }
  return React.cloneElement(
    path.node,
    path.node.props,
    ...path.traverseChildren(),
  );
}

export default function traverse(node, visitor) {
  const {
    Empty = defaultTraverse,
    Text = defaultTraverse,
    Fragment = defaultTraverse,
    DOMElement = defaultTraverse,
    ComponentElement = defaultTraverse
  } = visitor;
  const path = {
    node,
    kindOf,
    defaultTraverse() {
      return defaultTraverse(path);
    },
    traverse(childNode, childVisitor = visitor) {
      return traverse(childNode, childVisitor);
    },
    traverseChildren(childVisitor = visitor) {
      return React.Children.toArray(path.node.props.children).map(
        (childNode) => path.traverse(childNode, childVisitor)
      );
    },
    visitor
  };
  if (node === null || node === undefined || typeof node === 'boolean') {
    return Empty(path);
  }
  if (typeof node === 'string' || typeof node === 'number') {
    return Text(path);
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return Fragment(path);
  }
  const { type } = node;
  if (typeof type === 'string') {
    return DOMElement(path);
  }
  return ComponentElement(path);
}

// transpile.js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import traverse from './traverse';

const viewNodeTypes = ['div'];
const textNodeTypes = ['h1', 'p'];
const inlineNodeTypes = ['span', 'b', 'em'];

const dom2ReactNative = (node) => traverse(node, {
  ComponentElement(path) {
    if (path.node.type === 'img') {
      return React.createElement(
        Image,
        path.node.props
      );
    }
  },
  DOMElement(path) {
    if (textNodeTypes.includes(path.node.type)) {
      return React.createElement(
        Text,
        path.node.props,
        ...path.traverseChildren(),
      );
    } else if (viewNodeTypes.includes(path.node.type)) {
      return React.createElement(
        View,
        path.node.props,
        ...path.traverseChildren(),
      );
    } else if (inlineNodeTypes.includes(path.node.type)) {
      return path.node.props.children;
    }
    return React.cloneElement(
      path.node,
      path.node.props,
      ...path.traverseChildren(),
    );
  }
});

export default dom2ReactNative;
```